# Why is each layer taking the initial input array shape instead of the previous layer's output

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Each layer in my code shows it expects an array shape but received one same as the input array dimensions

I have commented after the first maxpooling layer just to give a hint on the error. If you take a look at the error, it expects (16, 64, 64, 64) but says it received (16, 128, 128, 1) which happens to be my input array.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv3D(64,3,activation= 'relu',padding='same',input_shape=(16, 128, 128 ,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(1,2,2),strides= (1, 2, 2)))

#model.add(Conv3D(128,3,activation= 'relu',padding="same"))
#model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2),strides= (2, 2, 2)))

#model.add(Conv3D(256,3,activation= 'relu',padding="same"))
#model.add(Conv3D(256,3,activation= 'relu',padding="same"))
#model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2),strides= (2, 2, 2)))

#model.add(Conv3D(512,3,activation= 'relu',padding="same"))
#model.add(Conv3D(512,3,activation= 'relu',padding="same"))
#model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2),strides= (2, 2, 2)))

#model.add(Conv3D(512,3,activation= 'relu',padding="same"))
#model.add(Conv3D(512,3,activation= 'relu',padding="same"))
#model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2),strides= (2, 2, 2)))

#model.add(Dense(output_dim= 4096,activation= 'linear' ))
#model.add(Dense(output_dim= 4096,activation= 'softmax' ))
```

The error i received is

> str(data_shape))
>
> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected max_pooling3d_4 to have shape (16, 64, 64, 64) but got array with shape (16, 128, 128, 1)

Why is it so? Thank you for any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to the input shape; rather, it is concerned with the shape of labels array you are providing to the model when training the model. This is clearly stated in the error:

> Error when checking **target**

Here "target" means the **output** of the model. In your minimal example, the output shape of pooling layer is `(16, 64, 64, 64)`:

> expected max_pooling3d_4 to have shape (16, 64, 64, 64)

However, you are giving it **outputs** of shape `(16, 128, 128, 1)`:

> but got array with shape (16, 128, 128, 1)

Comment: Input is a set of videos, 8 to be exact, with 16 frames from each. i didnt get the label part you were talking abt. Could you pls tell me how to deal with it.

Comment: @shjk If you don't have labels, then how do you want to train your model in a supervised way?! Surely you have labels and you are giving it to the model when calling `fit` (or `fit_generator`). So the problem is that the shape of labels array is not compatible with the output shape of the model.

Comment: I am using kth action dataset. I cudnt find any csv files for this. I quiet unclear about how to feed such a labelled dataset in supervised learning.

Comment: Incase i design a decoder for this, can i turn this supervised model to unsupervised?

Comment: @shjk I have not worked with that dataset, however if your task is "action recognition" (i.e. given an input video, tell me what action is being done) then you need (ground-truth) labels to provide to the model.

Comment: In what format and where should i provide such an input, as a csv file?

Comment: @shjk As a numpy array. Read [this guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) to better understand how Keras works. I strongly recommend to take a look at the examples provided in that guide.

Comment: @shjk Yes, it's possible to build an autoencoder (though, it does not help with classification task without having the labels). But I am not sure if it would perform with great accuracy (i.e. you may need to tune it). [Here](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) is an official tutorial on building autoencoders in Keras (though, it's on images, not videos).

Comment: Yes, i have read the keras blog. The above given architecture is for 3dconvnet specifically designed for video classification. I am supposed to give the output of last dense layer to a linear classifier.